# Ubuntu / Apache2: I cannot open port 443

Tags: networking, apache2, firewall, iptables

I am trying to install a SSL certificat on my Ubuntu 14 server (using apache 2). For some reason the port 443 appears to be closed

I installed and enable ssl

`/etc/apache2/ports.conf` is as followed:

```
Listen 80

#<IfModule ssl_module>
#       Listen 443
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
    NameVirtualHost 11.11.11.11:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

LISTEN

```
root@server01:/home/admin# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1317/amavisd-new (m
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1184/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1116/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2037/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1116/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2037/apache2
```

UFW

```
root@server01:/home/admin# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT** 
here my exemple.net-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName exemple.net
        ServerAlias www.exemple.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/exemple.net/
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/secure_access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/exemple.net.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/exemple.net.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/GandiXXXSSLCA.pem
        # SSLVerifyClient None

  </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @muru thanks for the answer; but when I check (in this site for exemple: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) it is said that the port 443 is closed.

Comment: What does `curl -I https://localhost` say?

Comment: curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Comment: That means it is listening. If Apache wasn't listening on 443, you'd get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused` instead.

Comment: yes 22 and 80 are open

Comment: So I suppose you just need to set up an HTTPS site on Apache for it to start working, since it is listening. Does any of your `sites-enabled` have an HTTPS component?

Comment: Yes my main site has a exemple.net-ssl.conf enabled and openssl is enabled

Comment: If that's the case, then there's some site misconfiguration, since `curl` reported an error.

Comment: OK, I put my site-ssl.conf as edit of my question. Anyway thanks a lot for the time helping. You're the best

Comment: Since the VHost is 11.11.11.11, a connect on localhost will fail with that error. Can you use `_default_` or `*` instead in the VHost?

Comment: Just did it. <VirtualHost *:443> still the same;

Comment: Apparently it was an issue with mi iptables: to open the port iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

Comment: :O Now here I thought the point of UFW was to manage iptables rules.

Comment: Yes I also thought it was. I have to find out why ufw is not managing ip tables ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the IP Address from NameVirtualHost 92.243.16.14:443 (you practically have binded all VirtualHosts on that IP Address) in order to listen on port 443 on all network interfaces (IPs):

NameVirtualHost *:443

Then you can differentiate domain by binding the VirtualHost on a specific IP address like so: VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443 VirtualHost 1.2.3.5:443 and so on...

To create as many SSL Vhosts as you like on your server with the VirtualHost and ServerName statements to differentiate the domains, you can use the following procedure for more further detailed configurations http://www.bytelinux.com/create-self-signed-certificates-enable-apache-ssl-ubuntu-14-10/

I'm not saying that is wrong to bind on an interface but if that IP Address changes then you wont be able to access your domain anymore and you can't access SSL locally (127.0.0.1).

Comment: thanks; muru had the same idea; not helping for this case but that's a good point in general not to bind the 443 to one ip

Comment: Have you removed the binding and still is not working?

Comment: Yes; apparently it was an issue with iptables

Comment: oh...that's a different story...so finally is now working?

Comment: Yes and no: my port is open but my SSL certificat is still not working: on openssl s_client -connect 92.243.16.14:443 I get Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Comment: I guess I have to go step by step ;-) but at least the port is now open

Comment: You can read this tutorial http://www.bytelinux.com/create-self-signed-certificates-enable-apache-ssl-ubuntu-14-10/ and inspire further on how you can generate and install self-signed certificates easily. You can use the bash script described there for certificate creation.Hopes it helps you!

Comment: Also I suggest to test the server with a graphical browser (chrome, mozilla etc) from a different host on your network since self-signed certificates generates warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Solution By MadHatter,

https://serverfault.com/questions/666696/ubuntu-apache2-cannot-open-port-443/666713?noredirect=1#comment814308_666713

> don't know much about ufw, but in this case I think it will be completely ineffective on INPUT traffic, because the rules that implement it come after a blanket DROP (the fifth rule in the INPUT chain). You can see from the packet counts on the later rules in the INPUT chain that no packets are ever getting as far as any of the rules that are supposed to send traffic to the ufw- chains (which I presume are intended to implement ufw policy).
>
> If you do
>
> ```
> iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
> ```
>
> that should open up your HTTPS port. Making that persistent across reboots I leave to you, as it is implementation-dependent."

Comment: @muru tahnks for the edit ;-)

Comment: sure. Could you add a link to discussion that lead to the answer?

Comment: getting 

iptables: Index of insertion too big.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is running and port 443 is also open, here you need to check for the IP 92.243.16.14 is configured or not using ifconfig command. because 443 is running on default interface.